# Linker scripts symbol declarations

Tags: c, linker

I am referring to [GCC Linker](https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs373/readings/Linker.pdf) document to understand linker script command. I have come across the difference between the source code symbol declaration and linker script symbol declarations, and got confused at paragraph:

> When a symbol is declared in a high level language such as C, two things happen. The first is that the compiler reserves enough space in the program’s memory to hold the value of the symbol. The second is that the compiler creates an entry in the program’s symbol table which holds the symbol’s address. ie the symbol table contains the address of the block of memory holding the symbol’s value. So for example the following C declaration, at file
> scope:

> int foo = 1000;

> creates a entry called ‘foo’ in the symbol table. This entry holds the address of an ‘int’
> sized block of memory where the number 1000 is initially stored.
> When a program references a symbol the compiler generates code that first accesses the
> symbol table to find the address of the symbol’s memory block and then code to read the
> value from that memory block. So:

> foo = 1;

> looks up the symbol ‘foo’ in the symbol table, gets the address associated with this symbol and then writes the value 1 into that address. Whereas:

> int * a = & foo;

> looks up the symbol ‘foo’ in the symbol table, gets it address and then copies this address into the block of memory associated with the variable ‘a’.

while

> Linker scripts symbol declarations, by contrast, create an entry in the symbol table but do not assign any memory to them. Thus they are an address without a value. So for example
> the linker script definition:

> foo = 1000;

> creates an entry in the symbol table called ‘foo’ which holds the address of memory location 1000, but nothing special is stored at address 1000. This means that you cannot access the value of a linker script defined symbol - it has no value - all you can do is access the address of a linker script defined symbol.

I am confused with linker symbol declarations statement "they are an address without a value". Could anyone help me understand this context ?

Comment: linker symbol does not have size or type, just address.  What confuses you?

Comment: I didn't get "Linker scripts symbol declarations, by contrast, create an entry in the symbol table but do not assign any memory to them. Thus they are an address without a value.". As i have understood, the linker symbol just creates an entry in the symbol table but instead of storing the address it stores a value, but in contrast to symbol declaration in c "the symbol table contains the address of the block of memory holding the symbol’s value"

Comment: No.  All entries in the symbol table are just a name and address, whether compiler creates them or linker script.  But when the compiler creates a symbol it can also allocate memory in a data segment.  The linker symbol does not do that.

Comment: The compiler creates memory to hold the value of symbol, but linker doesn't do that.